# How to enable blue/green deployment with CircleCI to ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-ecs, circleci, aws-code-deploy

I'm using CircleCI's aws-ecs orb to deploy to ecs. As far as I know the default deployment type is rolling update.

I searched for a solution, however the solutions are only for AWS CodeDeploy. The [CircleCI docs](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/aws-ecs#jobs-deploy-service-update) show support for blue/green deployment, but in the config I cannot set the deployment type.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/aws-ecs-orb/tree/master/src/examples) is the example that orb has. You could also use CodeDeploy to enable blue-green deployment, orb supports CodeDeploy via `deployment-controller` parameter